# services based architecture should not necessarily imply distribution?

Tags: web-services, architecture

In my workplace (and a lot of other areas), there is a lot of emphasis on building architecture around services. (I am working in an e-commerce startup). However, I think services are implicitly considered as distributed. I am a believer of the first law of distribution - "don't distribute". So, I believe that we should not un-necessarily complicate architecture. It should be an architecture which can evolve. So, one of the ways to approach the problem would be to create well defined namespaces and build code around it, but keep the communication via java api. (this keeps monitoring requirement low, and reliability/availability problems low). This can easily be evolved into a distributed architecture by wrapping modules into web service, as and when, the scale requirements kick-in. So, the question is - what are the cons of writing code as a single application and evolving into distributed services, rather than straight jumping into implementing web services based architecture? Am I right in assuming that services should imply the basic principles of design (abstraction, encapsulation etc), rather than distribution over network?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Distribution requires modularity. However, it requires more than just modularity: it also requires coarse-grained interaction between the modules.

For example, in a single-process ecommerce system, you might have separate modules for managing the user's shopping cart and calculating prices. They might interact by the cart asking the calculator to price an item, then another item, etc. That would be perfectly fine.

However, in a distributed system, that would require a torrent of small method calls, which is inefficient; you might get away with it if you used CORBA for distribution, but with SOAP, you'd be in trouble. Rather, you would want to have the cart ask the calculator to price the whole order in one go. That might be worse from a separation of concerns point of view (why should the calculator have to know about the idea of carts?), but it would be required to make the system perform adequately.

Related to granularity, there's also the problem of modules interacting via interfaces or implementations. With a single process, you can define a set of interfaces through which modules will interact; modules can pass each other objects implementing those interfaces without having to tell each other about the implementations (eg a scheduler module could be passed anything implementing `interface Job { void run(); }`). Across a network, the requirement for coarse grain means that any objects passed must be passed by value (because passing by reference would entail fine-grained calls back to the passing module - unless you were using mobile code, which you aren't, because nobody is), which means that both modules must know about and agree on the implementations of the objects.

So, while building a single-process system in a modular way makes it easier to implement SOA later, it doesn't make it as simple as wrapping each module in a SOAP interface. At least, not unless you build your system in a coarse-grained manner from the start, which means throwing away a number of sound and helpful good software engineering practices.